TP-Link USB hub not working properly on my Asus Zenbook 14
Last week I bought a usb 3.0 hub from tplink which offers 3 usb 3 ports and a gigabit internet port. I connected the hub to my Asus Zenbook 14 UM3402YAR laptop. After I wanted to test if the wired internet connection works, I ran an internet speed test and the first time in Ubuntu the connection simply dropped shortly after it went up to maximum downlink. I moved to Windows because I have a dual boot system to see if there does the same and the fact does it worked. Afterwards I wanted to transfer some files to my computer from a USB stick, and it read the USB stick very slowly and the HUB driver that comes with Windows failed. The data on the USB stick is safe. I could tell something was really wrong. I tried the hub to see if it's faulty using another computer and it works on two other machines without error. I did on the current Asus Zenbook laptop a file transfer test without the hub and it works without problems. I figured out that it's a problem with the laptop's usb port not knowing how to handle the hub properly. I tried the following:

uninstalled and reinstalled generic drivers
installed the drivers from the vendor
changing power settings to balanced or high power to see if it is a problem from the power save mode
disabling power save on the all usb drivers

I can't really find a solution on this. I read something about a setting called Disable Selective Suspend in the power plan settings > change advanced power settings, but there is no setting for me to change in that way. Also I only have the balanced power plan there. Any ideas how can I make my usb hub working? thanks for your attention

Also I forgot to tell the processor on my laptop is an AMD Ryzen 7 7730U. I have:
1x USB 3.2 Gen 2 Type-A and 2 x USB 3.2 2nd generation Type-C compatible display/power delivery port. The USB drivers as displayed by devicice manager are: 2x AMD USB 3.1 XHC, Generic SuperSpeed Hub, Generic Hub, 2x USB Composite, 2xUSB Root Hub 3.0

Update! After changing some registry settings to disable the selective suspend it is still working bad. Also that thing is not changing even if the laptop is powered from the charger.

It would be helpful if you provide a link to your particular TP-hub, what kind of cable it uses, and research/post hub internals using USBTreeView utility https://www.uwe-sieber.de/usbtreeview_e.html
